# Is there a way to launch exe application from firefox and chrome

Tags: cross-browser, exe

I have an intranet site, so i'm not worried about security. What I need to do is allow my users to launch putty.exe from a browser link. The point is that there are numerous putty connections on different ip's ports etc.

Currently we use IE and activex. But we want to use chrome or firefox.

I've heard of ie tab and locallink, but they're not that feasible.

Is there a way to launch a program from a link, crossbrowser?
ie `<a href="c:\program file\putty.exe -ip=2.3.4.5 -port=1111 -user=user -pass=pass">Putty</a>`

Comment: You can download and then run .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Being that the program you want to use is PuTTY, in you could do something like:

```
<a href="telnet://<your-ip and some other parameters>">Putty</a>
```

Which in Chrome and Firefox will prompt you to choose the appropiate program for that protocol  the first time, after that the program should start automatically...

You could also use `ssh` or `ssh2` instead of `telnet` if your client software (in this case PuTTY) has those URI schemes registered....

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. When I click the link it says it will open "...putty.exe" -ssh 1.1.1.1 -P 111 -l user -pw pass
but it launches putty but then still passes the uri hook (ie ssh) to putty so it ends up saying, cant find host ssh

i made the registry hook like this..  
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ssh\Shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\putty.exe\" %1"